# TypeScript 1.4 indentation issue

Tags: typescript, indentation, code-formatting, typescript1.4

I recently upgraded TypeScript to v1.4 (I'm using VS2013) and the code indentation formatting seems to have been changed with the update.

The way my code looked before was like this:

```
return this.doSomethingThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(()=>{
        // more code
    })
    .then(()=>{
        // even more code
    });
```

But since installing v1.4 the code now formats like this:

```
return this.doSomethingThatReturnsAPromise()
    .then(()=>{
    // more code
})
    .then(()=>{
    // even more code
});
```

Whenever I change it back to the way I used to have it and type something that formats the code it puts it back to the new way (which I really don't like).  Any ideas what I can check or change to make it go back to the way it was before please?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the author on the download site for WebEssentials. (You could also disable the WebEssentials extension to see if the behavior is caused by it).

Comment: Good idea, have tried disabling WebEssentials and it is not that which is causing this issue.  Have updated post due to these findings.

Comment: This maybe related https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1276

Comment: You may be right, but that seems to be to do with tab spacing (being 2 instead of 4) in VS2015, my issue seems to be with an indentation not being applied in VS 2013 when it should be, but not denying it could be related (I've updated my post to include the VS version I'm using).  I'm happy to raise this as a bug on the github site if I'm sure I'm not doing anything daft first though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a new bug so I raised it on Github : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1917

Observed it in https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript as well which simply calls the language service.